# pyqt QTreeWidgetItem double click connect

Tags: python, pyqt

Is it possible to connect a doubleclick event to a QTreeWidgetItem?

Something like this:

```
def test(self):
        print("hello")

childItem = QTreeWidgetItem()   
childItem.doubleClicked.connect(self.test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal you want is called `itemDoubleClicked` and belongs to `QTreeWidget` itself:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def handler(item, column_no):
    print(item, column_no)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QtGui.QTreeWidget()

    items = [QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem("item: {}".format(i)) for i in xrange(10)]
    win.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
    win.itemDoubleClicked.connect(handler)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help